# collect unreliable behavior in spark

Tags: apache-spark, filter, rdd, collect

I am little surprised with the unreliable behavior of collect. not sure whether this is an expected behavior.

I have a persisted DF - ext.
when I run a filter and then collect on it sometime it gives me value. where as some time it returns nothing.
not sure why I am getting this unreliable behavior. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

```
scala> ext.filter("sup = 12345678").collect()
res142: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array()

scala> 18/04/20 00:44:01 WARN ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0

scala> ext.filter("sup = 12345678").collect()
res143: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([222222,12345678,2017,1])
```

Very similar behavior for other filter operation.

```
scala> edgeDF.count() 
res95: Long = 65001895.
```

edgeDF is cached and i get same count every time. But i created another DF using edgeDF.

```
scala> val edgeDF1 = edgeDF.filter("s != sup") 
edgeDF1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sup: string, s: string]
```

then I cached it. Now count on edgeDF1 every time gives me different result.

```
scala> edgeDF1.cache() 
scala> edgeDF1.count() 
res84: Long = 16156590 
scala> edgeDF1.count() 
res85: Long = 16157825
```

Comment: Very similar behavior for other filter operation. scala> edgeDF.count()
res95: Long = 65001895. edgeDF is cached. and i get same count every time.

Comment: Very similar behavior for other filter operation. 
scala> edgeDF.count()
res95: Long = 65001895. 

edgeDF is cached and i get same count every time. But i created another DF using edgeDF; 

scala> val edgeDF1 = edgeDF.filter("s != sup") 
edgeDF1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sup: string, s: string]

then I cached it. Now count on edgeDF1 every time gives me different result. 

scala> edgeDF1.cache()
scala> edgeDF1.count()
res84: Long = 16156590

scala> edgeDF1.count()
res85: Long = 16157825

Comment: Please move the comments into question with code format.

Comment: What is the source data?

Comment: Actual source is a hive table. From there i have done select certain columns to create edgeDF dataframe. Strange thing is that count on this edgeDF is always same. On edgeDF after applying filter when i created edgeDF1 and then cached count is coming different.